# Phaser 3 - set min and max zoom levels

Tags: zooming, phaser-framework

I'm using Phaser to create an online comic. One functionality I want to have is the option to zoom into images, for the sake of legibility on small screens.

I'm using the following on a container holding the image.

```
container.scale = 1;

this.input.on('wheel', function (pointer, gameObjects, deltaX, deltaY, deltaZ) {
                    
    var x = deltaY * 0.002;
                    
    container.scale += x;
                
    console.log(container.scale);
                
});
```

So far so good, the image zooms.

I want to set a minimum zoom level of 1 and a maximum zoom level of 1.5.

I thought this modification to the code would do it:

```
container.scale = 1;

this.input.on('wheel', function (pointer, gameObjects, deltaX, deltaY, deltaZ) {
                
    var x = deltaY * 0.002;
                
    function between(x, min, max) {
        return x >= min && x <= max;
    }
        
    if (between(x, 1, 1.5)) {
        container.scale += x;
        console.log(x, container.scale);
    }
                
});
```

But the code won't fire at all. I've tried variations and gotten nowhere - can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The WheelEvent.deltaY read-only property is a double representing the vertical scroll amount in the WheelEvent.deltaMode unit.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WheelEvent/deltaY)

You're comparing the set amount the wheel is actually spinning versus that range, which is why it'll never fire. On my end your x value will be either 0.24 (down-spin) or -0.24 (up-spin) depending on the wheel spin direction.

This is closer to what you might want to be achieving:

```
    if((x < 0 && container.scale + x >= 1) || (x > 0 && container.scale + x <= 1.5)) {
      container.scale += x;
    }
```

Comment: That got it, thank you @Nemoverflow - and thanks for the link as well, useful info.